# Clojure does not have !=?

Tags: clojure

Does not exist?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does exist:

```
Clojure 1.2.0
user=> (not= 1 2)
true
user=> (not= 1 1)
false
```

Answer (score 16):

```
user=> (doc not=)
-------------------------
clojure.core/not=
([x] [x y] [x y & more])
  Same as (not (= obj1 obj2))
nil
```

Amusingly, you could define != to be the same as not= if you *really* wanted:

```
user=> (def != not=)
#'user/!=
user=> (!= 2 2)
false
user=> (!= 2 3)
true
```

Comment: I suspect that clojure eschews the != syntax in order to maintain the idiomatic usage of the ! character to indicate functions that must take place inside a transaction.

Comment: Indeed. In Java and similar languages, ! means negation. If not= were !=, it would be grossly inconsistent.

Answer (score 6):

In a lot of clojure code the ! char means that a function changes the state of something in a way you should watch out for. the [clojure transients](http://clojure.org/transients) make heavy use of these

```
compare-and-set! 
alter-meta!
conj!
persistent!
```

check out http://clojure.github.com/clojure/ and search for the ! character. these functions usually come with caveats like "must be free of side effects"

Comment: sorry if that post was putting ! functions in a bad light. they are really useful and are actually safe to use :)

Answer (score 4):

According to my google search "not=" is the equivalent but I have zero personal familiarity with Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason [`not=`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/not=) doesn't suit your purposes?